# AWS Typescript CDK: A version for this Lambda function exists ( 1 ). Modify the function to create a new version

Tags: aws-lambda, aws-cdk

Here is my CDK code:

```js
    const addVersion = (resourcePrefix: string, lambda: NodejsFunction) => {
      const version = new Version(this, `${resourcePrefix}Version`, {
        lambda,
      });

      const alias = new Alias(this, `${resourcePrefix}VersionAlias`, {
        aliasName: 'current',
        version,
      });

      alias.node.addDependency(version);
    }
```

The first deployment succeeds, subsequent deployments fail. I'm assuming it's because CDK is attempting to create a new version of the Lambda function each time even when the source code has not been modified. How can I get it to stop doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reference the Lambda's `currentVersion` property:

```js
new Alias(this, `${resourcePrefix}VersionAlias`, {
  aliasName: 'current',
  version: lmbda.currentVersion,
});
```

> [docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v2/docs/aws-cdk-lib.aws_lambda-readme.html#versions): The `fn.currentVersion` property can be used to obtain a `lambda.Version` resource that represents the AWS Lambda function defined in your application. Any change to your function's code or configuration will result in the creation of a new version resource. You can specify options for this version through the currentVersionOptions property.

Comment: This did not resolve the issue unfortunately. Is there a certain way I have to create the function? It's important to note I'm using the NodejsFunction construct, not a normal lambda.Function construct.

Comment: @AndrewAllison  It works fine with `NodejsFunction`.  Make sure to remove the `new Version(this, ...` and `alias.node.addDependency` lines.  Run [cdk diff](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/v2/guide/cli.html#cli-diff) to verify that your code is not silently causing a new Lambda version to deploy.